# Alegreya font package has several number and small caps problems

Tags: fonts, luatex

I recently updated my system (TeX Live 2019, LuaTeX Version 1.10.0), and I'm suddenly confronted with problematic `\textsc{}` input and a host of warnings regarding numbers. How can I address these issues?

```
%LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}
\usepackage[osf]{AlegreyaSans}

\begin{document}

Test. \textsc{Test.}

1234567890

\textsf { Test. \textsc{Test.} \\ 1234567890 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

After reinstalling TeXLive from TUG, I get the following .log:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (format=lualatex 2020.1.8)  8 JAN 2020 13:08
 restricted system commands enabled.
**alegreya-mwe.tex
(./alegreya-mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2019-11-06 2.69 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2019-11-06 2.69 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / conf
ig file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/sam/.texlive2019/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader “fontloader-2019-10-29.lua” from kpse
-resolved path “/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontl
oader-2019-10-29.lua”.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 4
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version “3.11”
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / callback h
andling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / Unicode he
lpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 5
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / resolver
s
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/sam/.texlive2019/texmf-var/lua
tex-cache/generic/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / auxiliar
y functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / multis
cript
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2019-11-10 3.11 luaotfload submodule / tounicod
e
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.097 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/sam/.texlive2019/texmf-v
ar/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc
! Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric da
ta not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.54 \normalsize

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

New warnings mention the common `fontspec` error that the fonts cannot be found.

Comment: Show your log-file.

Comment: I can’t reproduce your bug on my TeX Live 2019. Do you perhaps have an older version of the font file sitting around somewhere?

Comment: @Davislor I can't imagine I do, it's a new system as of yesterday. I'm using Fedora 31; perhaps the package in its respository is a little out of date?

Comment: Maybe. You might need the `ht-alegreya-fonts` RPM installed, or have an older version of a TeX Live package. Does installing `alegreya` through `tlmgr` fix this?

Comment: What does `luaotfload-tool --find=Alegreya` give you? When you give that filename to `otfinfo -i`, what version does it say you have?

Comment: Your system is not up-to-date, your luaotfload is clearly older than mine. And Alegreya is older too (I remember that there were a few bugs I reported here).

Comment: I don't use Fedora, but a brute-force solution to a distro having out-of-date TeX Live files is to install the distro from TUG into `/usr/local/`.

Comment: I've manually updated both the `alegreya` and `luaotfload` packages to the latest CTAN versions. Now it seems the issue might be with luaotfload-notdef.lua.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issues(s) you're encountering on my system (MacTeX2019, all updates current).

Comment: did you update the file name database by running mktexlsr?

Comment: The luaotfload-notdef issue is caused by an outdated version of the unicode-data package.

Comment: I've now completely reinstalled TeXLive from TUG, and I'm still encountering issues. `tlmgr update --all` responds with no updates available. Yikes, I'm absolutely lost.